# what to exclude for spring jax-ws in maven

Tags: spring, maven, jax-ws

I have been developing a Spring Web application. I need to add a web service functionality to the application. I am using Maven for dependencies and so far I am very content.

I will use Jax-WS for Spring and when I add the dependency like below :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

I get the error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate NamespaceHandler for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context]
```

I am 70% sure that this is because of same library components found more than once, but currently I am at loss of what to exclude from this dependency.

Any answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at [dependency exclusions](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html#Dependency_Exclusions)

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>*</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions> 
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

We use this, but I don't know how this list was derived:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```